# test input arrays in laravel 5.5 ignore empty or null input values

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I am currently testing a championship tree with 16 competitors.

Each competitor can be updated via a select combo.

Now, when testing this functionality in Laravel 5.5, I do:

```
$this->select([
        $competitor1->id,
        $competitor2->id,
        $competitor3->id,
        $competitor4->id,
        $competitor5->id,
], 'fighters[]')
        ->press('update');
```

that will put a value on the 5 first combos.

Now, If I try to insert a `null`, or a `""` , it is ignored and removed from the select method, so I can only test the first entries, I cannot test the first and the fourth only for example.

Is it something I am not doing properly?

Comment: Is this in Dusk?

Comment: nop, I still test like in 5.1 : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing - it is just functional testing, not in browser